# Horizontally center row div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center all columns in a row Horizontally center in bootstrap 4.

the first row is correctly aligned center, but the 2nd row columns, not working properly, although I used same class for it.

my code as below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>

    .bg{
        background: url('bg.jpg') center / cover no-repeat;
        height: 600px;
    }
    
    .row1{
        padding-top: 200px;
    }
    
    .row2{
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
    
    img{
        box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .img1{
        height: 164px;
    }
    
    .img2{
        height: 258px;
        width: 238px;
    }
    
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid bg">
    <div class="row justify-content-center row1">

          <img src="img1.jpg" class="img1" alt="Italian Trulli">

    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center row2">
        <div class="col col-lg-2">
          <img src="img1.jpg" class="img2" alt="Italian Trulli">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2">
          <img src="img1.jpg" class="img2" alt="Italian Trulli">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2">
          <img src="factory.jpg" class="img2" alt="Italian Trulli">
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result as below (2nd row is not correctly aligned)

[image]

Comment: `col`s are centered horizontally. It's just that the image sizes you set in your css do not cover the entire width of the `col`. So, ' visually' it appears that they are not centered. Remember, with the code you shared you are centering horizontally the `col` divs, not the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cols are centered horizontally. It's just that the image sizes you set in your css do not cover the entire width of the col. So, ' visually' it appears that they are not centered. Remember, with the code you shared you are centering horizontally the col divs, not the images

See example below

As you can see the cols ( red border ) are centered horizontally inside the row ( blue border ), but the imgs are smaller in width so they are not centered

```css
.bg{
        background: url('bg.jpg') center / cover no-repeat;
        height: 600px;
    }
    .col {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .row {
     border:1px solid blue
     }

  
    
    img{
        box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
        border-radius: 6px;
   
    }
    
    .img1{
        height: 164px;
    }
    
    .img2{
        height:50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    
    .col {
    border:1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container-fluid bg">
   <div class="row justify-content-center row2">
     <div class="col col-2">
       <img class="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
     </div>
     <div class="col col-2">
       <img class="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
     </div>
     <div class="col col-2">
       <img class="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```